# Validations not working in MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and installed `fluentvalidation` mvc but the validations are not working, though the program is working fine

While executing the program, the `fluentvalidation` functions are not working. I have done all of the steps, but it is not working

Comment: Please do not post code as pictures, use the site formatting and paste it as text here so you have more chance of people helping you out!

Comment: i am new to this site ,is there any video how to post the questions in this blog.i will maintain standards from next post onwards.

Comment: Not to worry, [you can read up here on how to ask a question for future reference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [This is also a very good blog on the topic](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     //Method in controller
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Save(BacklogModifyVM item)
     {
        //Validate VM
        var validator = new BacklogModifyVMValidator();
        var result = validator.Validate(item);
        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            return InvalidDataResponse(result.Errors);
        }
      }
      //entity class
      public class BacklogModifyVM
      {
         public decimal BacklogId { get; set; }
         public string BacklogTitle { get; set; }      
         public decimal BackLogStatusId { get; set; }
         public string Owners { get; set; }        
         public decimal ProjectId { get; set; }
         public string Description { get; set; }
         public decimal? EpicId { get; set; }       
      }
      //validator class
      public class BacklogModifyVMValidator : AbstractValidator<BacklogModifyVM>
      {
          public BacklogModifyVMValidator()
          {
            RuleFor(x => x.BacklogId).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(-1).NotEqual(0);
            RuleFor(x => x.BacklogTitle).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.BackLogStatusId).GreaterThan(0);
            RuleFor(x => x.ProjectId).GreaterThan(0);
            RuleFor(x => x.Owners).Matches(@"((\d+)((\.\d{1,2})?))$");
           }
      }
```

Comment: can anybody explain about fluent validation one example.

Comment: see i have updated code

Comment: Thank you for your quik response. now i got some idea about fluent validation